# Sending email in a queue such as MSMQ

Tags: windows, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, smtp

I have asp.net MVC 3 application that sending various emails such as client registration, activation etc

Currently using smtpclient and smtp server authsmtp.com. In last 3 months there was number times application used to hang when sending email and smtp is not responding.

I am now required to review the process and improve with following improvement.

1.) Application should not hang when smtp server is not responding.
2.) Queue email for later delivery if smtp server is not available. Re-try delivery for next 24 hours
3.) Add extra logging for email queued, sent or failed (After 24 hrs)

I would like to know what will best option to implement the above requirement.

The application is hosted in windows azure environment.

I thought to use MSMQ as provides message queueing and I can log the details once each task is started and completed.

Reference : http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Sending-email-from-ASP-NET-MVC-through-MVC-and-MSMQ-Part1.aspx

The problem is that MSMQ is not supported on windows azure.

Please advise ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an example on WindowsAzure.com that covers a similar topic as this http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/multi-tier-web-site/1-overview/